# Is possible to cross the Bering Strait without flying?

Tags: transportation, overland, adventure, asia, north-america

I'm planning a trip and one of my main points is not to fly unless absolutely necessary. My biggest problem is how to cross from Asia to America without a plane. If it's absolutely impossible to cross the Bering Strait without flying, which is the shortest route? Maybe a small airplane?

Comment: You mean a small airplane that doesn't fly?

Comment: No, I prefer to cross by boat, but if there are not other option, I prefer a small airplane or a helicopter than a big aircraft :)

Comment: potential duplicate: http://www.horizonsunlimited.com/hubb/northern-asia/ferry-over-bering-strait-20915

Comment: @Andra: That's an old thread in another website. I don't think that's duplicate :) Anyway, good link! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crossing Bering Strait on a boat does seem *possible* but it's going to be difficult *practically*. [Adam Katz put together a bunch of notes on how to do this](http://www.geekeasy.com/travel/articles/bering_strait.shtml). From the looks of it, it appears you might have to pay your way through it on commercial fishing vessels which operate in the area.

According to this resource, [navigating Bering Strait is hard because of weather/geographical conditions and the legality of getting permission to leave Russia](http://www.angusadventures.com/beringstrait.html). From the linked source:

> It is recommended to cross in a seaworthy vessel capable of handling
>   intense storms.  It is possible to cross the narrowest part of the
>   Bering Strait in a smaller boat such as a kayak during a calm period
>   of weather, however a support boat would be recommended.  The problem,
>   however, is the possibility of having the boats confiscated upon
>   reaching shore.

and (assume there are similar problem the other way)

> **How do you cross the Bering Strait legally?**
>
> This is very difficult.  Not only is it necessary to arrive in Russia
>   in an official port of call, but it is also necessary to depart from
>   an official port of call.  We have not heard of any adventurers who
>   have received permission to arrive or depart from the remote shoreline
>   of Russia.

[A discussion on Lonely Planet's Thorn Tree forums mentions previous attempts and further information](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=1423699). A pertinent point is while it may be possible to *cross*, going on from there onwards to rest of Alaska/America has its own problems too.

> It should be noted that Nome is not a usual port of entry into the
>   USA, and it could be a problem as there is only a part time
>   Immigration and Customs agent. In addition, from Nome to the rest of
>   Alaska would then require an expensive flight to either Anchorage or
>   Fairbanks. Also from Provideniya there are only occasional flights to
>   Anadyr, the Chukotka capital that is considered one of Russia's less
>   desirable destinations.