# What routes are there to cross the Pacific East-to-West (without flying)?

Tags: sea-travel, ships, pacific-ocean

This question is similar to [Is possible to cross the Bering Strait without flying?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3907/is-possible-to-cross-the-bering-strait-without-flying) but broader.

If you depart from North America, how can you reach any East Asian destination by cruise, ferry, cargo ship or anything that doesn't fly?

Are there regular cruises Seattle - Hawaii - Tokyo? Or something similar?

Answer (score 8):

There are certainly cruises from America to Asia, you'll need to get to Los Angeles or San Francisco but from there you can get to China (and from there you can get a train or ferry to most places -- although sadly not the Philippines, which reminds me I meant to ask a question about that).

For example [Princess Cruises](http://www.princess.com/) Voyage Number H419A (can't link directly to the page but you should be able to search for that) goes from LA departing April 3 and arrives in Shanghai on April 25. It calls at Honolulu (April 8), Guam (April 17), Taipei (April 21), Okinawa (April 23). I don't think it runs often, maybe once a year, but it's definitely there. I've seen other similar cruises but they too don't run often -- a travel agent should be able to help.
One web site that seems to offer great searches for specific start and end ports is  http://cruisesheet.com/ .  ([found in this other post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/is-there-a-directory-list-or-other-way-to-search-for-ocean-crossing-cruises-fr))

Alternatively you could go on a cargo cruise, here's a link for [West Coast USA to Asia](http://www.freighterexpeditions.com.au/freighter-cruise-asia-to-west-coast-usa-copy), they claim they run every month -- however that site looks suspiciously like a reseller and they may not actually have what they claim.

Finally, if time and money isn't an issue you could do it in the other direction, New York to Southamptom on the [Queen Mary 2](http://www.cunard.com/cruise-types/transatlantic-cruises/). Take the train or ferry to Europe, then train across Europe to Asia.

Comment: To answer my own aside, apparently the Philippines to mainland Asia is mostly covered well in this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/543/is-it-possible-to-get-from-the-philippines-to-taiwan-to-japan-or-the-reverse-w

Comment: this is a great answer, but I don't find the specifics out there today... does anyone have an update on a specific trip like the Princess voyage mentioned?

Comment: ... to answer my own question... There are some very interesting links in this post--- http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/is-there-a-directory-list-or-other-way-to-search-for-ocean-crossing-cruises-fr

Comment: (+1) Someone selling trips on a freighter would not run anything, for this type of travels, you always have to go through an agent and their general conditions typically mention the fact that they are just a reseller and do not organise anything. On the other hand, the largest container ships really are on a somewhat regular schedule, with several ships serving the same line every few weeks/month so a monthly departure is completely believable. [Here is one random example of such a network](https://www.cma-cgm.com/products-services/line-services/solution) (and CMA-CGM takes passengers).

Comment: Royal Caribbean cruises once a year, it seems, from Vancouver, BC (Canada) to Yokohama via Alaska.  We're sailing on Radiance of the Seas on that route in September, 2020.